# Get URLs of links in a rectangular region

Tags: java, javascript, html, browser, browser-extension

Often I need the URLs of the links in a rectangular region on an HTML page. This rectangular region is often the column of a table. I need those URLs in my java program which has to do further processing with them.

I've been thinking about this problem for more then a month but didn't come up with a good solution. Here some of my ideas:

**Approach 1:** The easiest way would probably be to have some browser extension where you can draw a rectangle like in MS Paint and the URLs of all the links within the rectangle get copied to the clipboard (for example separating different links by the line separator character). Then my java program would only have to read out the clipboard to extract the URLs.

Unfortunately, I've never developed a browser extension so I know very little about it.

**No approach:** Just trying to select the links and copy them pressing `ctrl+c` to the clipboard and then parsing them using Java won't work because the selection will also include links of the other columns.

**Approach 2:** Since I have experience with javascript I also thought about some greasemonkey script which keeps track of the URLs you hover during holding a certain key on the keyboard. Unfortunately, javascript can't copy the URLs to the clipboard so the transfer of them to the java program could be more involved.

**Approach 3:** A third approach could be to directly work with the HTML code of the page and somehow identify the table. But here you would have to parse HTML, also no cool thing.

Do you have a solution to this problem? It would be fine for me to find a solution which works in Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a column of a table, why don't you copy the table to excel and then extract the links using this [how-to](http://howtouseexcel.net/how-to-extract-a-url-from-a-hyperlink-on-excel).

As another approach, browser extensions are easy to make and something I believe one should know as they are very powerful (in terms of possible applications). 
Check out [this lifehacker post](http://lifehacker.com/5857721/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension) on creating browser extensions. Also you can use [extensionizr](http://extensionizr.com) to easily create browser extensions.

EDIT:

Also for *Approach 2*, try console.log(url) on the script instead of clipboard and then copy the entire list of URLs from console.